Summability condition for Hilbert space operator with respect to an ON basis
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ some ON-basis for $H$. Suppose $A:H\to H$ is a bounded linear operator that fulfills the following summability condition
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left| \langle Ae_n,e_m \rangle\right|<\infty .$$
Here we just assume the summability for some specific ON-basis, it might not be true for others.

Does the above condition imply that $A$ is compact?

Is there any standard term for this condition (or perhaps some equivalent condition)?



Yes. Your condition implies that
$$\sum_{n\ge1} \sum_{m \ge 1} |(Ae_n \mid e_m ) |^2 < \infty$$
and the latter is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \|Ae_n\|^2 < \infty \tag{1} $$
by Parseval's inequality.  Operators that satisfy (1)  are called Hilbert Schmidt and they are compact. Moreover, the Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\|A\|^2_{HS} : = \sum_{n \ge 1} \|Ae_n\|^2$ is independent of the choice of ON basis $(e_n)$.

Should'nt the condition for that instead be
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left| \langle Ae_n,e_m \rangle\right|^2<\infty .$$
Otherwise I do not see how you  utilize Parseval

@Accto3 W.l.o.g we may suppose $|A|<1$. In that case $| \langle Ae_n, e_m \rangle|<1$ so $| \langle Ae_n, e_m \rangle |^{2}\le | \langle Ae_n, e_m \rangle |$

Yes, but how do you show the reverse implication? The claim was that the condition was equivalent to the HS-property. Not that it just implies the HS property.

@Accto3 You are right, only one implication holds. My bad.

Also, while the HS condition is indeed basis independent I don't see how that has any bearing on whether or not the provided condition is basis independent. But thank you for settling the compactness issue.
